# Statistical test to assess the strength of the assertion "time series' values stayed the same"

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, trend, test-for-trend

The title somewhat gave my question away, but here goes...

I have a time series of values covering a certain time span...

If I chart it, I can visually conclude values roughly stayed the same. That is, if I draw a regression line, the slope is very near 0.
But, if that slope is slightly above or below 0, I could just as well conclude the data shows a small uptrend or downtrend.

So, my question is: Is there any statistical test I could use to feel confident that the values of the time series were not significantly increasing or decreasing over the observed period of time?

One idea I had was the following: If some values in the last quarter of the time series fall above the 3rd quartile of all values AND some values in the last quarter of the time series fall below the 1st quartile of all values, then it is unlikely the time series exhibit a significant uptrend or downtrend.

I think a concrete example would make this easier to understand:

Imagine a machine that burns a fuel to generate power. As time passes, if the components of the machine do not have adequate heat dissipation, producing the same amount of power requires increased amounts of fuel.

Testing the machine and its ability to dissipate heat involves letting it run for a rather long period of time at a constant power output, while monitoring the amount of fuel it consumes over that period of time.

So, you end up with a time series of fuel consumption and the goal is to have a test to decide whether a steady state was achieved.

Comment: It sounds like you want the Chow test.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow_test  for example.

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld Thanks! I'll add a concrete example to my initial post.

Comment: How about using the Cox and Stuart test?